# nginx This site can't be reached error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, load-balancing

I'm new to nginx & ubuntu. I [refer this link](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/developer/204405534/install-nginx-on-ubuntu) & setup nginx in my localhost. It was works fine & welcome page diplays when I hit the **localhost**. [refer the attached image]
[localhost and other 2 sites][Click here for see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/op5bg.jpg)

when I hit other sites from browser its says **This site can't be reached error**

plz help me to sort out this issue.

```
/etc/nginx# ls -R sites-*
sites-available:
default  ve-server1.com  ve-server2.com

sites-enabled:
default  ve-server1.com  ve-server2.com
```

**1st file**

```
server {
listen   80;
server_name  www.ve-server1.com;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://ve-server1.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

listen   80;
server_name ve-server1.com;

access_log /var/www/ve-server1.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /var/www/ve-server1.com/logs/error.log;

location / {

root   /var/www/ve-server1.com/public/;
index  index.html;
}
}
```

**2nd File**

```
server {

listen   80;
server_name  www.ve-server2.com;
rewrite ^/(.*) http://ve-server2.com/$1 permanent;
}

server {

listen   80;
server_name ve-server2.com;

access_log /var/www/ve-server2.com/logs/access.log;
error_log /var/www/ve-server2.com/logs/error.log;

location / {

root   /var/www/ve-server2.com/public/;
index  index.html;
}
}
```

Here is **www** folder files hierachy

```
/var/www# ls -R
.:
html  ve-server1.com  ve-server2.com

./html:
index.nginx-debian.html

./ve-server1.com:
logs  public

./ve-server1.com/logs:
access.log  error.log

./ve-server1.com/public:
index.html

./ve-server2.com:
logs  public

./ve-server2.com/logs:
access.log  error.log

./ve-server2.com/public:
index.html
```

My ubuntu version 16.10

Thanks
Jenny